# count distance strings/number in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, distance

I am trying to get your  help to find the logic this, how can I count a distance to the target in an array

let say I have an array

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "x" , "z" ]
```

i want to find distance "b" to "x" ? 
how about iif that array have empty string also?

```
like ["a", "b", "c", " ", "d", "x" , "z" ]
```

Comment: You mean distance between indexes (their position in the array)? `indexOfX - indexOfB `

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by distance? Also, please provide [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: does a distance count over the length? as example has `"z"` the same distance from `"a"` as `"a"` from `"b"`?

Comment: yes right @PatrickEvans

Comment: What about duplicates, say `["a", "b", "c", " ", "d", "x" , "c", "z" ]`? If you want the distance from "c" to "z", what result do you expect? Also, what if one or both are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let input = ["a", "b", "c", " ", "d", "x" , "z" ]

function findDistance(source, target){
 return Math.abs(input.indexOf(target) - input.indexOf(source))
}

console.log(findDistance('b','x'))
```

Answer (score 1):

A difference approach by using the array as infinity array.

```js
function findDistance(array, a, b){
    var delta = array.indexOf(a) - array.indexOf(b);
    return Math.min(
        Math.abs(delta),
        Math.abs(delta + array.length),
        Math.abs(delta - array.length)
    );
}

let input = ["a", "b", "c", " ", "d", "x" , "z"]; 
    //             ^                   ^                        
    //             1                   5          |1 - 5|     ->   4 
    //             1                   5          |1 - 5 + 7| ->   3 <==
    //             1                   5          |1 - 5 - 7| -> -11

console.log(findDistance(input, 'b', 'x'));
console.log(findDistance(input, 'x', 'b'));
```

Comment: What does adding / subtracting array length do? Why can't you just subtract 1 from 4?

Comment: it finds the distance of the items in an infinite array, which means it starts at the end again.